# Validar formulario de login con js

Tags: javascript, html, login

estoy trabajando con una pagina web en la cual el usuario debe pasar por un login y quiero que sea un poco más seguro que cuando solo le pones el required en el html, estuve investigando y llegue a este metodo, pero no me funciona, no se que puede ser pero este es mi codigo:
Quiza tenga algo mal en la sintaxis pero para mi lo más probable es que este llamando mal al archivo, ya cheque y la ruta esta bien, cabe aclarar que si funciona mi login, osea si esta bien la conexion, pero si dejas los campos vacions y le das ingresar te deja entrar.

----------------LOGIN.HTML------------------

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Formulario de Login</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, intial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">

</head>
<body>

    <form action="validar.php" method="post">

<div class="login-wrap">


    <div class="login-html">



        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Inciar Sesión</label>

        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab"></label>
        <div class="login-form">

            <div class="sign-in-htm">
                <div class="group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="label" >
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="clave"  id="clave" class="label" >
                </div>


                    <div class="group">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" id="ingresar" value="Ingresar">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </body>
```

------------VALIDAR2.JS---------------------

```
   var btn = document.getElementById('ingresar');
var clave = document.getElementById('clave');
var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario');



btn.addEventListener('click', function(evt){

      if(clave.value === ''){

          console.log('el campo contraseña es obligatorio')
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;

      }else if(usuario.value === ''){

      console.log('el campo de usuario es obligatorio')
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;

      }else if(usuario.value.length > 30){

        console.log('El nombre del usuario es demasiado largo')
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;

      }




});
```

VALIDAR.PHP

```
  <?php

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['clave'];


$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"" ,"J", "u257375416_bdbd");
$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' and clave='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas>0) {
header("location:index2.php");


  }else {
  echo "Error en la autenticacion";
  }

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Answer (score 2):

Espero te funcione, dejo la explicación comentada, cualquier duda hazla saber :D.

```js
/*No es recomendable declarar variables de forma lineal, hazlo por separado */

var btn = document.getElementById('ingresar');
var clave = document.getElementById('clave');
var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario');

/*en tu login te falto agregarle un id a tu botón y pasarle tu funcion validar2(), 
yo lo hago con listeners para no poner funciones js en el HTML, buenas prácticas, 
valido que no vengan vacios los campos y agrego la funcion de evt.preventDefault() 
como su nombre lo indica previene o cancela el evento si es que fuera cancelable en este caso 
el submit lo es y retorno un false para que no siga ejecutando la estructura del if*/

btn.addEventListener('click', function(evt){

      if(clave.value === ''){
        
          console.log('el campo contraseña es obligatorio')
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;
      
      }else if(usuario.value === ''){
      
      console.log('el campo de usuario es obligatorio')
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;
      
      }else if(usuario.value.length > 30){
      
        console.log('El nombre del usuario es demasiado largo')
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;
      
      }
    
  


});
```

```html
<form action="validar.php" method="post">

<div class="login-wrap">


    <div class="login-html">



        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Inciar Sesión</label>

        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab"></label>
        <div class="login-form">

            <div class="sign-in-htm">
                <div class="group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="label" >
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="clave"  id="clave" class="label" >
                </div>


                    <div class="group">
                    <input type="submit" id="ingresar" class="button" value="Ingresar">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Copie el codigo tal como me dijiste, pero no me funciona, voy a actualizar mi codigo en mi pregunta por si me equivoque en algo, gracias

Comment: En el HTML parece que falta la referencia al archivo VALIDAR2.JS
<script src="VALIDAR2.JS" type="text/javascript" />